# How to update FileField filename after it's saved in Django and using S3 as the storage

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I have a model that has a FileField. I want to save a generated file content before I send it to a 3th party service, after I have the response, I would like to rename it without changing the content.

I think the code below would generate another file on S3 instead of renaming it to the final name.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    record = models.FileField()

model.record.save('initial_filename', ContentFile(generated_content))
model.record.save('final_filename', model.record.read())
```

Comment: You can do something like this: record = models.FileField(upload_to=some_method). Then define the method(e.g some_method(instance, name)) and rename your file before saving it.

Comment: That is not what I try to achieve, I saved the file with a temp name first then after sending to a 3rd party service, I want to rename it.